# Why installing php7.4 on ubuntu 20 I have php 8 in the console?

Tags: php, ubuntu

Installing php7.4 on ubuntu 20(aws server) I have php 8 installed.
I tried to disable it and enable 7.4.
All my output commands below show valid output, but restarting apache I have php8 anyway:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-38-186 : ubuntu :~$ cd /etc/php
ubuntu@ip-172-31-38-186 : ubuntu :/etc/php$ ls -la
total 36
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root 4096 Jul 22 11:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 96 root root 4096 Jul 25 03:59 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jul 22 11:28 5.6
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jul 22 11:28 7.0
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jul 22 11:28 7.1
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jul 22 11:28 7.2
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jul 22 11:28 7.3
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Jul 22 11:23 7.4
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Jul 22 11:28 8.0
ubuntu@ip-172-31-38-186 : ubuntu :/etc/php$ uname -a
Linux ip-172-31-38-186 5.8.0-1041-aws #43~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 15 11:07:29 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

ubuntu@ip-172-31-38-186 : ubuntu :/etc/php$ php -v
PHP 8.0.8 (cli) (built: Jul  1 2021 15:26:46) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.8, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.8, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
ubuntu@ip-172-31-38-186 : ubuntu :/etc/php$ sudo a2dismod php8.0
Module php8.0 already disabled
ubuntu@ip-172-31-38-186 : ubuntu :/etc/php$ sudo a2dismod php8
ERROR: Module php8 does not exist!
ubuntu@ip-172-31-38-186 : ubuntu :/etc/php$ sudo a2dismod php8.0.8
ERROR: Module php8.0.8 does not exist!
ubuntu@ip-172-31-38-186 : ubuntu :/etc/php$ sudo a2enmod php7.4
Considering dependency mpm_prefork for php7.4:
Considering conflict mpm_event for mpm_prefork:
Considering conflict mpm_worker for mpm_prefork:
Module mpm_prefork already enabled
Considering conflict php5 for php7.4:
Module php7.4 already enabled
ubuntu@ip-172-31-38-186 : ubuntu :/etc/php$ sudo service apache2 restart
ubuntu@ip-172-31-38-186 : ubuntu :/etc/php$ php -v
PHP 8.0.8 (cli) (built: Jul  1 2021 15:26:46) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.8, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.8, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

restarting OS did not help.
How to setup php 7.4 ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please run the below command and then check php vrsion on ubuntu .

```
1. apt-get install -y software-properties-common
 2. add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php -y

 3. apt-get update -y



4. apt-get install -y php7.4 libapache2-mod-php7.4 php7.4-curl php7.4-gmp php7.4-mbstring php7.4-phpdbg php7.4-sqlite3 php7.4-zip php7.4-bcmath php7.4-dba php7.4-imap php7.4-pspell php7.4-sybase php7.4-bz2 php7.4-dev php7.4-interbase php7.4-mysql php7.4-readline php7.4-tidy php7.4-cgi php7.4-enchant php7.4-intl php7.4-odbc php7.4-xml php7.4-cli php7.4-fpm php7.4-json php7.4-opcache php7.4-snmp php7.4-xmlrpc php7.4-common php7.4-gd php7.4-ldap php7.4-pgsql php7.4-soap php7.4-xsl php7.4-mongodb


5.sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4
```

now check  php version

Thanks

Comment: Thanks!, it helped, but could you please to explain what was key of this salvation? I had php 7.4 ebfore running last command, but seems I run 7.4 php priorly...

Comment: sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4
  is command to you change php version if you have installed multiple php.

Comment: Good answer, but it would be even great if you explained what each command did. That way, it might also help future visitors that might have similar, but not exactly the same, issues. Always seeing answers as a teaching opportunity greatly improves the quality of the answers and this site as a whole.